# jQuery Cycle 2 - Uncover effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, cycle2

Wanted to use the 'uncover' effect on a slideshow but it seems that it doesn't work using jQuery Cycle 2.

It is working fine using the old jQuery Cycle plugin. Please see code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNBapZ)

```
$(function() {
    $('#uncover').cycle({
       fx: 'uncover',
       direction: 'down' // one of up|down|left|right  default=left
    });
});
```

Am I missing something? Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [Cycle 2 API](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) says:

> The following transition names are available by default and more can be added with plugins: **fade**, **fadeout**, **none**, and **scrollHorz**.

So you will probably have to add the additional **fx** effect **uncover** via a plugin.

Here is GitHub repository, which provides a plugin with the effects from Cycle 1: https://github.com/Spark-NF/cycle2-cover

From the description:

> Plugin for cycle2 implementing the original cycle's cover and uncover transitions.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thank you so much for the help! :)